# package org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb doesn't exist

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb

When I try to build my Maven project I get an error for `package org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb does not exist`. I have a dependency for it as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also added:

```
<repository>
    <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
    <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
</repository>
```

I've tried checking the version in my program with `System.out.println(org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersionString());` but I get an error because `Version` isn't recognized.

For my project I am trying to import `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties`.

Any ideas on why the package can't be found?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong dependency. `javax.persistence` jar does not have that package.
Instead, include the below dependency in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency has the required package.

Answer (score 0):

**Because,** your using **older version** of eclipseLink. JAXBContextProperties class is **only available from v 2.4.0**.

From the [java doc](http://javadox.com/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.5.0/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/JAXBContextProperties.html).

> Since:
>   2.4.0

So, if you need this class **use v2.4.0 or higher.**